# SCM Sync configuration plugin doesn't commit/push

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have installed SCM Sync configuration plugin(0.0.10) to save my jenkins settings in my git repository.

I have set the git url repository but the plugin does not commit/push, see the screenshot

[image]

I tried:

- The private key is in `~/.ssh/id_rsa` with the `chmod 600`
- The root user is own of the `id_rsa` and the `.ssh` directory
- The `.ssh` directory has the permission `700`
- I did the same for `jenkins` OS user
- I can clone the repository(from the console) using the ssh private key, so this means that everything is working

The screenshot of the plugin's status message

[image]

as you can see, the plugin copy all the files to the folder that I imagine this folder should be the git repository.

The plugin webpage (https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/SCM+Sync+configuration+plugin) we can see the same "error" and the message `To use a Git server with SSH, you have to accept the server SSH key before using the plugin (same for using Git in Jenkins jobs).`, OK, but I guess I already did.

The plugin's Troubleshootings says the it uses `~/.ssh/` to commit the settings

https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/ScmSyncConfig+Troubleshootings

I really like the plugin idea and I'd like to use it but I can't.

I use ubuntu 14.04 at AWS and my git repository is bitbucket.

What's wrong?

Comment: Hello, do you know what they actually mean by "To use a Git server with SSH, you have to accept the server SSH key before using the plugin (same for using Git in Jenkins jobs)."  - more specifically - accept it where? What are they talking about?

Answer (score 2):

I solved the issue, it didn't work because Jenkins was using the OS user `Tomcat7`, to check what OS user the Jenkins is using just go to option in Jenkins `Manage jenkins > System Information` and look for `user.name`, my case was `tomcat7`.

To solve just check the path of the user, the path can be found in `user.home` , in my case was `/usr/share/tomcat7` and I just copy the ssh key files to `/usr/share/tomcat7/.ssh`

The files were

- /usr/share/tomcat7/.ssh with `chmod 700`
- /usr/share/tomcat7/.ssh/id_rsa with `chmod 600`
- /usr/share/tomcat7/.ssh/id_rsa.pub with `chmod 600`

I guess the `id_rsa.pub(publick key)` is not necessary, after that, the plugin could sync with my repository.

Comment: is the OS user used in place of `git config --global user.name`?

Answer (score 1):

I was also facing same issue. In my case the user was root and home directory was /var/jenkins_home. I was using bitbucket repository.

First created the public and private key using following command

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "jenkins@<mydomain>.com"
```

ps: the file name should be id_rsa, if you provide other file name for your private key this won't work.

Copied public key to bitbucket repo settings -> access keys -> add key

private key to root's home directory /root/.ssh/id_rsa

Comment: I still have an error. I can ssh into the Jenkins server, `su jenkins` then  `cd /var/lib/jenkins/scm-sync-configuration` and `git pull` from there and everythings fine but I still get plugin errors